# PHP cURL from localhost getting Missing Parameters error

Tags: php, curl, localhost

I am trying to send a cURL post request from my localhost, but I am getting Missing parameters error.When I try from REST client mozilla addon it is working fine. Below is my php code .

```
$file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'AMZREO');
$fh = @fopen($file, 'w+');
foreach($input as $curl_response)
{
   fputcsv($fh, $curl_response, ',', '"');
}
// ... close the "file"...
@fclose($fh);
$post = array(
            'file'=>'@'.$file
        );
print_r($post);
$header[] = 'Authorization: Token '.$token;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url.'?target='.$target);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP200ALIASES, array(400, 500));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Below is the response

```
print_r($response);
{"status": "Failure", "message": "Missing Parameters"}
```

And I am able to see created file in my temp folder.  And when I print_r the $post array I am getting this result.

```
Array
(
    [file] => @C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Temp\AMZEE93.tmp
)
```

Please help me in this regard.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to use `http_build_query($post)` in the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`

Comment: @NigelRen, eventhough same error Missing Parameters

Comment: OK - sometimes it's the simple things which solve the problems, but without being able to test it is guesswork.

Comment: my OS is windows 10 64 bit and is there any influence? and is there anything that I need to add / change in php.ini ?